JanusGraph - "Expire lock on KeyColumn" Preventing Deletion/Drop of Graph
When executing the query via Gremlin:
g.V().drop().iterate()
I get this message:
Expired lock on KeyColumn \[k=0x0x5000000000326A80, c=0x0x02\]: lock timestamp 2024-11-05T12:28:00.196116Z Micros is older than storage.lock.expiry-time=PT5M

Is there a way to remove expired locks?
I've checked if there are any outstanding transactions via the Gremlin command:
graph.getOpenTransactions()
And I can't find any references to this error message which provide a solution.
I wondered if this was caused by an index that got stuck that I can't delete.  To solve that, I've tried using these commands to disable the index so I can delete it:
gindex = mgmt.getGraphIndex("byNameComposite")
mgmt.updateIndex(gindex, SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX).get()

But I then get this error:
Update action \[DISABLE_INDEX\] cannot be invoked for index with status \[INSTALLED\]

This is with cassandra 3.0 and elastic search 6.6.0 powering JanusGraph.
